# Combining heterogenous features in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm doing binary classification over some documents whose features are already extracted and given in a text file. My problem is that there are textual features and numerical features like years and some other.
One sample is given in this format:

```
label |title text |otherText text |numFeature1 number |numFeature2 number
```

I'm following the documentation about [feature unions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) but their use case is a bit different. I do not extract the the features from another feature because these numerical features are already given.

Currently I'm using the setup in the following way:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('features', Features()),

('union', FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[
        ('title', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='title')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ])),
        ('otherText', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='otherText')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ])),
        ('numFeature1', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='numFeature1')),
        ])),
        ('numFeature2', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='numFeature2')),
        ])),
    ],
)),
('classifier', MultinomialNB()),
])
```

The Feature class is also adopted from the documentation:

```
class Features(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, posts):
    features = np.recarray(shape=(len(posts),),
                           dtype=[('title', object),('otherText', object),
                                  ('numFeature1', object),('numFeature2', object)])

    for i, text in enumerate(posts):
        l = re.split("\|\w+", text)
        features['title'][i] = l[1]
        features['otherText'][i] = l[2]
        features['numFeature1'][i] = l[3]
        features['numFeature2'][i] = l[4]

    return features
```

My Problem is now: How do I add the numerical features into the FeatureUnion? When using a CountVectorizer i get "ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words" and using a DictVectorizer with only one entry doesn't strike me as the way to go.

Comment: Just use ItemSelector() class with key='numFeature1' and 'numFeature2'

Comment: this returns `ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions`

Comment: Show the code for your entire pipeline.

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

the `TfidfVectorizer()` object has not been fitted with data yet.

Before constructing the pipeline, do this -

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
vec.fit(data['free text column'])
pipeline = Pipeline([
('features', Features()),

('union', FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[
        ('title', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(key='title')),
            ('tfidf', vec),
        ])),

        ... other features
```

This helps if you want to fit your data again for test purposes... because for test data the pipeline would automatically use transform() function for the `TfidfVectorizer` instead of fit() function which you have to explicitly do before constructing the pipeline

Comment: I use `pipeline.fit(train.data, train.target)` to fit my data after constructing the pipeline just like the documentation does. My question was what steps I need to take to integrate the remaining non-textual features into the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

What ItemSelector() does is, picks data from the given `dict`(X) according to the `key` supplied in the constructor and returns a one dimensional `[n,]` array.

This type of `[n,]` array is not handled correctly by the `FeatureUnion`. `FeatureUnion` requires an array of 2 dimensions from each of its internal `transformers` in which the 1st dimension (number of samples) should be consistent, which can be finally stacked horizontally to combine the features.

The second operation in your first two transformers (`TfidfVectorizer()`) takes this `[n,]` array from ItemSelector and outputs a valid `[n,m]` type of array where `m = number of features extracted from raw text`.

But your 3rd and 4th transformers contain **only** `ItemSelector()`, so it outputs **`[n,]`** array. That is the cause of errors.

To correct this you should reshape the output of `ItemSelector` to `[n,1]`. 
Change the following code in `ItemSelector.transform()` (**I'm assuming you are using ItemSelector code from the link you specified**):

**Original**

```
data_dict[self.key]
```

**New**

```
data_dict[self.key].reshape((-1,1))
```

The `reshape()` will format your `[n,]` to `[n,1]` which can then be used by the FeatureUnion to append the data correctly.

Comment: Please see my related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221558/featureunion-with-heterogenous-features-valueerror-blocks0-has-incompatib).